# is it possible to create custom AWS CLI commands?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

Not sure this is the right place to ask but I'll go ahead anyway.

I want to modify the `aws s3 sync` command so that it does not override newer files on the destination.  Currently it compares the file size and timestamp and if either are different then the file at the source is copied to the destination.

Having a look at the AWS CLI source code it seems possible to simply modify the python code here

```
class SizeAndLastModifiedSync(BaseSync):

    def determine_should_sync(self, src_file, dest_file):
        same_size = self.compare_size(src_file, dest_file)
        same_last_modified_time = self.compare_time(src_file, dest_file)
        should_sync = (not same_size) or (not same_last_modified_time)
        if should_sync:
            LOG.debug(
                "syncing: %s -> %s, size: %s -> %s, modified time: %s -> %s",
                src_file.src, src_file.dest,
                src_file.size, dest_file.size,
                src_file.last_update, dest_file.last_update)
        return should_sync
```

But not being much of a python expert I am not sure there are other considerations that would prevent these modifications from working.

It seems all I would need to do is add a check to see if the dest_file timestamp is greater than the src_file timestamp - after resolving things like timezones etc.

Any pointers on the best approach would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused.  According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html), *"The default behavior is to ignore same-sized items unless the local version is newer than the S3 version."*  Isn't that what you are wanting?

Comment: If the size or timestamp is different then the source overrides the destination, it does not check if the destination is newer than the source - see the code above from the aws s3 sync function.  In any event I just modified the code in the file directly and it works now.